# php smarty syntax error

Tags: php, syntax, smarty

I'm new in smarty!I have a loop to print a table!but it's make synatc error what's wrong ?

```
{foreach $messages as $message}
<tr style="{if !$message->read }font-weight:bold;{/if}">
    <td style="width: 3%; background: #EFEFEF" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="selected[]" class="selected" value="{$account->username}{chr(22)}{$account->email}" /></td>
    <td style="width: 3%;" align="center"  >{$smarty.get.offset+($message@index+1)}</td>
    <td style="width: 20%;" >{$message->from}{if $message->firstname || $message->lastname}<span style="font-size:10px;font-weight:normal;color:#666"> <br />{$message->firstname} {$message->lastname}</span>{/if}</td>
    <td style="width: 46%;" ><a href="{$smarty.server.PHP_SELF}?mod=message&amp;caption=get&amp;id={$message->id}">{$message->subject}</a></td>
    <td style="width: 30%;" >{lib_abstracts::convertTime($message->cDate, '', TRUE, TRUE)}</td>
</tr>
{/foreach}
```

Comment: What is the syntax error it reports?

Comment: Syntax Error in template "D:\Apache2\htdocs\portal\admin/../admin/templates/listMessage.tpl" on line 96 " <tr style="{if !$message->read }font-weight:bold;{/if}"> " - Unexpected " }", expected one of: "|" , "}" , "*" , "/" , "%" , "+" , "-" , ""&"" , ISIN , ISDIVBY , ISNOTDIVBY , ISEVEN , ISNOTEVEN , ISEVENBY , ISNOTEVENBY , ISODD , ISNOTODD , ISODDBY , ISNOTODDBY , "==" , "!=" , "(>,gt)" , "(<,lt)" , "(>=,ge)" , "(<=,le)" , "===" , "!==" , "(%,mod)" , "(&&,and)" , "(||,or)" , "xor"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have white space in here `->read }` remove this and it'll be work

```
<tr style="{if !$message->read }font-weight:bold;{/if}">
```

Comment: @user848689: Just asking, didn't want to say you should not accept it. You can accept any answer you love, even if it does not fully answers your question. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @hakre: So remove your beautiful comments from my questions!

Comment: @Hamid Seyyedi: Your questions?

Answer (score 1):

Your `foreach` syntax is incorrect. You're using PHP style `foreach`. Smarty's is a bit different. **Note: your syntax is valid for Smarty 3. If you're using Smarty 2.x, use:**

```
{foreach from=$messages item=message}
  ....
{/foreach}
```

[Smarty foreach docs](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.foreach)

Comment: it's released in smarty 3 http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.foreach.tpl